# Possessive pronouns in research papers

Tags: pronouns, possessives, research

Contrast:

> In order to develop a relationship between the energy spectra and their corresponding Fourier transforms...

with

> In order to develop a relationship between the energy spectra and the Fourier transforms corresponding to these spectra

The first, in my opinion, sounds much smoother and more natural.  But I'm using a possessive personal pronounce with "spectra".  Is this allowed in a formal document like a research article?

...or is there a better option?

Comment: *Their* can be legitimately used for any plural noun. *They*: "used to refer to two or more people **or things** previously mentioned or easily identified." (emphasis mine)

Comment: I don't think you should go sleepless over this. Choose whichever one and then proceed to sleep soundly at night.

Answer (score 3):

If you are concerned about using a "personal" possessive determiner for something which is not a person, don't be.

> **their** *determiner*
>   **1** belonging to or associated with the people **or things** previously mentioned or easily identified:
>   *parents keen to help their children*
>
> [[ODO]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/their) (my emphasis)

Note that it isn't a possessive pronoun: a pronoun is a word which **stands for** a noun, and a possessive pronoun is a word like *mine, yours, theirs:*

> That car is my car
>   That car is mine (where *mine* is a possessive pronoun standing for *car*)

Comment: The issue of the personal and the possessive is secondary or actually, incidental, to the question. :)

Comment: @Kris I don't understand your comment; the question is entirely about *their* which the OP mistakenly assumes is personal and a pronoun.

Comment: The OP was presumably told that personal pronouns should not be used in scientific papers. This is incorrect; the person who told him this presumably meant that personal pronouns ***referring to the authors*** should not be used in scientific papers. While I would disagree with this, there are definitely some fields and journals for which this is the custom.